# Keras: error when compiling the model with custom loss after adding Masking layer

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I used my custom loss to train a model without masking layer for several times and it occurred to me I forget masking layer. Then I add a masking layer to the top of my model but I got an error when compiling the model:

```
ValueError: weights can not be broadcast to values. values.rank=0. weights.rank=2. values.shape=(). weights.shape=(None, 3521).
```

The length of sequence is 3521. I don't know why the model without masking layers can be compiled with my custom loss but the one with masking layer cannot. I think the reason may be my custom loss is not compatible with masking layer but I cannot find out how to modify it.

Here are the codes:

```py
# model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Masking(mask_value=-1.0, input_shape=input_shape, name='Masking'))
model.add(LSTM(nhidden, return_sequences=True, dropout=dropout_rate, name='LSTM1'))
model.add(LSTM(nhidden,return_sequences=True, dropout=dropout_rate, name='LSTM2'))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(units=nstatus, activation='softmax'), name='Output'))

# loss
def myloss(alpha, gamma=2.):
    alpha = tf.constant(alpha, dtype=tf.float32)
    alpha *= 4
    def get_loss(y_true, y_pred):
        """
        Args:
            y_true(tensor): shape=(batch_size, #points_of_curve, #classes)
            y_pred(tensor): shape=(batch_size, #points_of_curve, #classes)
        """
        # reshape alpha to (batch_size, #points_of_curve, #classes) to
        # apply weights to each points' prediction
        alpha_r = tf.reshape(alpha, [1, 1, -1])
        multiples = tf.concat((tf.shape(y_true)[:2],[1]), axis=0)
        alpha_r = tf.tile(alpha_r, multiples)

        y_true = tf.cast(y_true, tf.float32)
        y_pred = tf.clip_by_value(y_pred, K.epsilon(), 1. - K.epsilon())
        ce = tf.multiply(y_true, -tf.math.log(y_pred))
        gamma_base = tf.multiply(y_true, 1-y_pred) + tf.multiply(1-y_true, y_pred)
        gamma_weight = tf.pow(gamma_base, gamma)
        with_gamma = tf.multiply(gamma_weight, ce)
        fl = tf.multiply(with_gamma, alpha_r)
        loss_per_point = tf.reduce_sum(fl, axis=-1)
        loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss_per_point)
        return loss
    return get_loss
```

Here is the summary of the model:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
Masking (Masking)            (None, 3521, 1)           0         
_________________________________________________________________
LSTM1 (LSTM)                 (None, 3521, 64)          16896     
_________________________________________________________________
LSTM2 (LSTM)                 (None, 3521, 64)          33024     
_________________________________________________________________
KPD_Output (TimeDistributed) (None, 3521, 4)           260       
=================================================================
Total params: 50,180
Trainable params: 50,180
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Comment: please add the model code, model.summary(), data shapes, etc.

Comment: @Andrey I've updated the question. Thank you for replying!

Comment: is it possible to mask the -1 of y_true inside the loss? is this what u are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Marco Cerliani  Yes. I padded the sequence to the same length with -1 when preprocessing the data but labeled the padded time steps with the last label of original sequence (these labels are not -1 because it will mess up one-hot encoding). Now I want to mask the padded time steps in my custom loss.

Comment: you have to reserve a special character for padding in order to apply Mask layer or build a custom procedure inside the loss

Comment: @Marco Cerliani Do you mean I should use a new label for padding steps? For example, I have 4 classes before which will be encode to 4d vectors. Now I should use 5 classes, one of which is padding, and they will be encode to 5d vectors. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, thanks for @Andrey's and @Marco Cerliani's responding. Here's the solution: **DO NOT reduce the dimension at the final step of your loss function so that it can return a tensor whose shape is (batch_size, sequence_length) as the loss**. The following words are some thinking and guess so you can choose to ignore them.

I didn't reserve a special label for padding at the beginning so I spent some time on putting the labels right, but I still got the same error. I doubted it's not the problem of my wrong approach of labeling (even if I use the wrong, it'll cause bad results of training instead of the above error). I noticed that the error message told me the weight's shape is (None, 3521) and then started thinking: isn't the loss a scaler? Therefore, I removed the `tf.reduce_mean()`, the final step of my loss so that keep the dimension of loss (None, 3521), then my model can be complied again. Why my custom loss works when compiling the model without masking layer but does not when compiling the model with masking layer? I guess the masking layer need the loss for every point instead of a number so that it can apply the mask to the loss. I didn't read the source code of tf so it's just my guess. Hoping someone knowing the mechanism to provide an answer for this!